# Class library - Sql server ce 4 - relative path in connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I've done a project (class library) where my integration tests are located and also the .sdf file. How can i specify a relative path in the connection string and app.config for the .sdf file ?

I've tried using Data Source=MyTestDB.sdf

and it's located in C:\Dev\MySolution\MyNinthProjectInSolution\MyTestDB.sdf

Comment: Does the answer and link helped ?

Comment: Configure the connection string at runtime